# How to handle MouseUp event in DataGridTextColumn of DataGrid in context of MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, prism

I've seen a really interesting behaviour. If I handle `MouseDown` event `DataGridTextColumn` of `DataGrid`, then I can easily invoke a `HelloCommand`. Hovever, I cannot handle `MouseUp` event. In this occasion `HelloCommand` is just not fired.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">            
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding FirstName}" >
          <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp"> <!--EventName="MouseDown" handles perfectly-->
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding  DataContext.HelloCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                     </i:EventTrigger>
                   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                   <TextBlock Text="I am a TextBlock!:)"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I've tried to use  `RoutedEventTrigger`. However, it is not invoke a `Command`.

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <helper:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp">
       <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetNewDataCommand}" />
   </helper:RoutedEventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

where `helper:RoutedEventTrigger`:

```
public class RoutedEventTrigger : EventTriggerBase<DependencyObject>
{
    RoutedEvent _routedEvent;
    ...
}
```

How can I handle "MouseUp" of `DataGridTextColumn` of `DataGrid` an event?

Comment: Try using PreviewMouseUp

Comment: @Rya I've tried to use. However, there is no result.

Comment: @RyanSearle yeah, I've tried to use `PreviewMouseUp`. However, there is no result, no invoking of `Command`.

Comment: Try using MouseLeftButtonUp instead

Comment: @RyanSearle yeah, I've tried to use `MouseLeftButtonUp`. However, there is no result, no invoking of `Command`.